# Filtering a .txt file using a regular expression and a second file

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression, filter

I have a file.txt (it does not have the same number of columns for each row):

e.g.

```
1 21:10 21:23 
2 1:94 1:100 1:123 
3 14:1 14:60 14:23
```

I have another file (file2.txt) that contains 4 columns (separated with " ")

```
a 21 20 60
b 2 80 90
c 14 50 100
d 2 10 20
e 14 1 12
```

I want to check the initial part for each row of the 1st file (21;1;14, it is equal for each row) and select the elements that have the part after ":" between the value in the second file (3th e 4th column) iff the 2th column is equal to the part before ":"

**e.g. of computation:**

```
> file.txt: 1th row: 21:10 21:23 --> 21 is in a in file2.txt so  20<10<60 NO 
> but 20<23<60 is true so I take it.. and so on, I see for each row in file2.txt
```

**another example:**

```
file.txt: 3th row: 14:1 14:60 14:23 --> 14 is in c and e in file2.txt so

50<1<100 NO  (for c)
50<60<100 YES  (for c)
50<23<100 NO (for c)
1<1<12 YES  (for e)
1<60<12 NO  (for e)
1<23<12 NO(for e)
```

if an element if between 2 value (for only a row for file2.txt) I take it.

> **Ex. of results:**

```
1 21:23 
2 14:1 14:60
```

(row 2 is eliminated because 1 is not contained in any cell of column 2 of file2.txt)

Comment: [edit] this question to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I have no idea to how solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean `<=` instead of `<` since `1<1<12` is **not** `YES`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    cnt[$2]++
    beg[$2,cnt[$2]] = $3
    end[$2,cnt[$2]] = $4
    next
}
{
    out = ""
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,parts,/:/)
        key = parts[1]
        for (j=1; j<=cnt[key]; j++) {
            if ( (beg[key,j] <= parts[2]) && (parts[2] <= end[key,j]) ) {
                out = out OFS $i
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if ( out != "" ) {
        print ++outNr out
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
1 21:23
2 14:1 14:60
```

The above was tested using the 2 input files you provided:

```
$ tail file1 file2
==> file1 <==
1 21:10 21:23
2 1:94 1:100 1:123
3 14:1 14:60 14:23

==> file2 <==
a 21 20 60
b 2 80 90
c 14 50 100
d 2 10 20
e 14 1 12
```

and the expected output you provided.

Comment: The code works but in file1.txt for each row I have 2 elements in first and second row: e.g 002 "C" 21:10 21:23 ; 003 "F" 1:94 1:100 1:123. Using the script I lose the information of the first 2 column, how can I put them in the final output ?? (002 and "C" for first row and so on)

Comment: It's important when asking questions about how to manipulate some data that you post a realistic example of that data and not some different input. If the example in your question isn't truly representative of your real data then fix your example so it is then feel free to leave me a comment and I'll take another look,

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you